# Discord.py bot doesn't dm user

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots, dm

If someone says hey in chat I want the bot to dm them, but it gives absolutely no errors an doesnt work either

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  if message.content.lower == "hey":
    await message.author.send("heyo")
    await message.add_reaction(":b:")
  await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Did you setup discord intents?

Comment: yes, i was missing out on brackets after the lower function though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried tinkering with your code and something I noticed was that you weren't calling the lower function correctly. `lower` should be `lower()`. That allowed the bot to at least DM me.

(Note: I also fixed the add_reaction error by using the write emoji format needed)

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.lower() == "hey":
        await message.author.send("heyo")
        await message.add_reaction("️")

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i completely missed out on the brackets